# how to execute function over the data frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

With the help of forum member, following code has been created.

```
foo <- function(x,y) prop.table(table(sign(x), y), 1)
```

Now, I am not sure how I would execute this on my dataframe where x would be from column number 2 to 10 and y would be only one fixed column within the dataframe.

Your help would much appreciated.

best regards
Lutfor

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply` to loop over the column of interests, and do each calculation against the fixed column i.e (assuming the fixed column is column 1),

```
sapply(df[2:10], function(i)prop.table(table(sign(i), df[,1]), 1))
```

Comment: Hey, `df[1]` is a list and `table()` will get an error. It should be `df[, 1]`, right?

Comment: My pleasure! I make a supplementary here. Given the aforementioned function `foo`, this answer can be simplified as `sapply(df[2:10], foo, df[, 1])`

Comment: Yes,  I just like to write the full code for both clarity and readability

Comment: thank you so much for your help...it really ease my life

Answer (score 0):

If you like using the `tidyverse` you could also use `purrr`'s `map` function.

Say this is your data.frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- as_tibble(cbind(rep(1:2, 5), matrix(rnorm(10 * 9), ncol = 9)))
```

And the fixed column is the first column, `V1`:

```r
df %>% select(2:10) %>% map(function(col) foo(col, df$V1))
```

```
$V2
    y
         1     2
  -1 0.625 0.375
  1  0.000 1.000

$V3
    y
       1   2
  -1 0.5 0.5
  1  0.5 0.5

$V4
    y
       1   2
  -1 0.4 0.6
  1  0.6 0.4

$V5
    y
             1         2
  -1 0.6666667 0.3333333
  1  0.4285714 0.5714286

$V6
    y
       1   2
  -1 0.6 0.4
  1  0.4 0.6

$V7
    y
             1         2
  -1 0.3333333 0.6666667
  1  0.5714286 0.4285714

$V8
    y
             1         2
  -1 0.4285714 0.5714286
  1  0.6666667 0.3333333

$V9
    y
             1         2
  -1 0.5714286 0.4285714
  1  0.3333333 0.6666667

$V10
    y
       1   2
  -1 0.4 0.6
  1  0.6 0.4
```

You got a list of `table`s. If you wish to get a data.frame back like in @Sotos answer, you can do:

```r
tab_to_vec <- function(tab) c(tab[, 1], tab[, 2])

df %>% select(2:10) %>% map_dfr(function(col) tab_to_vec(foo(col, df$V1)))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 9
     V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.625   0.5   0.4 0.667   0.6 0.333 0.429 0.571   0.4
2 0       0.5   0.6 0.429   0.4 0.571 0.667 0.333   0.6
3 0.375   0.5   0.6 0.333   0.4 0.667 0.571 0.429   0.6
4 1       0.5   0.4 0.571   0.6 0.429 0.333 0.667   0.4
```